# What's better: Checking Input only in JFrame class or in other classes too

Tags: java, swing

So I was wondering if lets say I have a JFrame with a method which checks textfields etc:

```
private void removeFish() throws Exception{
    if(ftfNameFish.getText().toString().trim().length() ==0){
        throw new Exception("empty name");
    }

    String weight = ftfMinWeight.getText().replace('g',' ').trim();    
    if(weight.length()==0)
        throw new Exception("invalid weight");

    weight = ftfMaxWeight.getText().replace('g',' ').trim();    
    if(weight.length()==0)
        throw new Exception("invalid weight");


    dbF.removeFish(new Fish(this.ftfNameFish.getText(), Integer.parseInt(ftfMinWeight.getText().replace('g',' ').trim()), Integer.parseInt(ftfMaxWeight.getText().replace('g',' ').trim()), ftfFirstOccurence.getText()));
    lblMessage.setText("fish removed"); 
}
```

Is it better to ignore the values of the strings etc in the JFrame method removeFish() BUT check them in the class method (dbF.removeFish) or should I do both?  Or is it enough to check them before I call the method dbF.removeFish?

Comment: From a purely OO point of view, it's best to isolate the responsibility to the class level and encapsulate the functionality. The question is too broad to be answered within the context of SO. Generally speaking, you will want some kind of validation at the model level, this doesn't mean you can't have additional validation higher up, but the model level is ultimately responsible for ensure the validity of the data - for example, if you know the model require a `int` value, then you could validate the client data as such, but leave the model to determine if he value is within range

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this
You **could have** UI/Form (client-side) data validation **or not**
But you **MUST** have data validation on backend (server, dbF, anything before an action for data)

Since your form and your business module are in one place, you would ignore the UI data validation unless you like keep the CPU working for double reason.

If it was a web application, you could add client(UI/form) data validation to help user and server for faster checking. But data must be validated again at the server side too(dbF).

Answer (score 0):

Always that you have that question ask to your own if the general method need to be reused. And in the case of yes ask your own if you want always do this step.

The question is really not bad. Most of validations use both checkings but the meaning is different.

When you fall in a exception (as you are programming) when using methods or interfaces of a class it exception is usually made to give the info of what you are missing or what this class need to work as intended. Is more relative to the programmer. You are doing it so good.

By other side when you ensure that the value passed to some method (when using an instance of a class) is of the type X, not void.. or basically that it is what you need to pass to the method/function (because it needs the value for working). It is more relative to validations, checkings.. or to the user.
It validation is common to cause changes in the view. If you decide to show a red X in case of incorrect value, for example.

You can understand it is not needed if you gonna check the value and ensure it will be right. Then it is not needed to do a exception in the method, but the right way is doing both two. Then in case you tommorrow want to use that method and you fall in the exception you will know what the method require. Just reading "Empty name".

The you will program the validation to ensure the user type a correct value, for example.

I dont know If I explain correctly what I mean.

Edit: As @user7859067 say it is highly recommended to validate the data before continuing a process within a method of which you have intention of instantiate. Because that is what is going to cause your application bug, crash without knowledge of what is going on.

As summary. A good way to see it is if you imagine a text-box as input. It pass a value to a function and this function require a number.
If you let the user to pass a string, you need to implement a way to say stop before value pass to the function.
If you only let the user write a number the application will work but your function already accept a string without error. And you are giving the error management to the library/function that will fail because there is not a number to operate and the remote person who programmed the exception to give you the info of what happens.
"All what your code can control is intended to be in your code. The problem is the time."